# Entering date as a char in C, can't work out how to avoid the /

Tags: c, date, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char day[3] = {""};
    char month[3] = {""};
    char year[5] = {""};

    printf("Date of Birth: ");
    scanf("%s[^/]%*c%s[^/]%*c%s", &day, &month, &year);
    printf("\n1. %s", day);
    printf("\n2. %s", month);
    printf("\n3. %s", year);
}
```

I'm trying to enter the date and discarding the `/`.  Currently, the whole entry gets stored into char day[3] and the other three chars are left blank.

I am using char because I want to keep the leading zeros and I am using the strings to make a file name without the `/`.

Comment: How about reading the whole string and then using `strtok`?

Comment: If you're going to read data into these buffers there's no reason to pre-initialize them. Also since these are numbers you don't need to declare `char` buffers. Just use the original buffer, tokenize, and convert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first `%s` in your format string is capturing everything up to the first whitespace character, which is your whole date string.  The `[^/]` the immediately proceeds it it matching exact characters.

What you want is to use the `%[` format specifier to grab characters up to a `/`.

```
scanf("%2[^/]%*c%2[^/]%*c%4s", &day, &month, &year);
```

Also note the inclusion of a field width to each to prevent writing past the end of the given buffers.

Comment: I think this stems from a frequent misunderstanding that the string set format specifier is `%s[]` or `%[]s` when, as you show, it should be `%[]`.

Comment: For safety, you should probably use `%2[^/]` and `%2s` to avoid overrunning the buffer.

Comment: @Unn Good call.  Updated.

Comment: @dbush thanks that's amazing. It's so complicated and I'm still trying to get my head around it but it works amazingly.

Comment: Since you are reading a response to a prompt from `stdin`, it may be a good idea to read, and ignore, the rest of the line. This gets rid of whitespace and stuff that couldn't be parsed, and puts `stdin` in a "clean" state for the next read.